# Problem Installing Jupyter Notebook for PyXLL

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook, pyxll

I am trying to install Jupyter Notebook on PyXLL but the 'Jupyter Notebook' tab isn't showing under the PyXLL Example TAB in Excel.
Despite the Miniconda console confirms it's already installed.

[image: Anaconda Prompt (miniconda3) console]

[image: PyXLL Example TAB in Excel]

Thank you in advance

The expected outcome is :
[image: PyXLL tab]